# Is there exist a real continuous function f such that $\int_0^x f(t) dt =mf(x)$ for some real constant m?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions, continuity

**The Question is:** Is there exist a real continuous function f such that $\int_0^x f(t) dt =mf(x)$ for some real constant m?

**My Approach:**
Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{m} \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt$.

Now if this $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous , then $\forall ε>0 \exists δ>0$ ; such that $|f(x)-f(c)|< ε$ whenever $|x-c|<δ(c,ε)$. Here we will choose $δ(ε,c)=ε$

Case1 :($x>c\geq0$)
Here, $$|f(x)-f(c)|=|\int_0^x fdt-\int_0^c fdt|$$$$=|\int_c^x fdt|$$
Now $|\int_c^x fdt|\to 0$ as $|x-c|<ε$ for all ε>0.(Put m=1)
$\therefore |f(x)-f(c)|<ε$ whenever $|x-c|< δ$.

Similarly Case 2,3,4 can also been proven where $c>x>0;c<x<0$ and $x<c\leq0$ respectively.

Now since this **c** is arbitrary ,so f(x) continuous in $\Bbb R$. □

**Conclusion:** So I think such function Exists.

Please verify my solution and let me know ,my mistakes  ,if any. **Thank You**.

Comment: So, $f(x)=\frac{1}{m} \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt$, but what is $f(t)$?!

Comment: $f$ can be a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$

Comment: Which one? Any?

Comment: Yes , f can be any.

Comment: Suppose $f$ is the constant function $1$. Then $f(x)=\frac1m\int_0^x1dt = \frac1mx$ is not constant anymore.

Comment: There is no solution here to verify. Do you, understand what the question is?

Answer (score 4):

We can also try to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus here to try and find a solution. We start with the equalty

$$mf(x)=\int_0^x f(t) \mathrm{d}t.$$

Differentiating this then yields

$$mf'(x)=f(x),$$

which is a separable differential equation with solutions on the form

$$f(x)=Ce^{x/m}$$

for $C\in\mathbb{R}$. Finally, we can plug this into the original integral equation, which yields that

$$mCe^{x/m}=\int_0^xCe^{t/m}\mathrm{d}t=\biggl[mCe^{t/m}\biggr]_0^x=mC(e^{x/m}-1),$$

i.e.

$$mC=0.$$

Now if $m=0$, then $f$ is the zero function (check this with the original equation), and if $m\neq0$, we also have the zero solution. It follows that the only possible solution to the integral equation is

$$f(x)\equiv0.$$

Comment: Not the best answer, despite the upvotes: the OP looks for *continuous* functions $f$, but your reasoning works only for *differentiable* functions.

Comment: @AlexM. It's easy to prove that any continuous solution has to be differentiable though. If $f$ is continuous, then by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, this mean that $x\mapsto \int_0^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$ is differentiable. But since this is just $mf$, it means that $f$ is differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

If $m=0$, then by differentiating with respect to $x$ one gets $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, so $f=0$.

Let us assume in the following that $x \ge 0$, but the same argument holds for $x < 0$ as well. If $m \ne 0$, then
$$f(x) = \frac 1 m \int _0 ^x f(t_1) \, \mathrm d t_1 \ , $$
so we may replace $f(t_1)$ inside the integral by $\frac 1 m \int _0 ^{t_1} f(t_2) \, \mathrm d t_2$, which gives us
$$f(x) = \frac 1 {m^2} \int _0 ^x \mathrm d t_1 \int _0 ^{t_1} \mathrm d t_2 \, f(t_2) \ ,$$
so we may replace once more etc. In the end, we get that for every $k \in \mathbb N \setminus \{0\}$ it is true that

$$ f(x) = \frac 1 {m^k} \int _0 ^x \mathrm d t_1 \int _0 ^{t_1} \mathrm d t_2 \dots \int _0 ^{t_{k-1}} \mathrm d t_k \, f(t_k) \ .$$

We shall change the order of integration by noticing that $0 \le t_k \le t_{k-1} \le \dots \le t_1 \le x$, which means that (replacing $t_k$ by just $t$)

$$ f(x) = \frac 1 {m^k} \int _0 ^x \mathrm d t \int _t ^x \mathrm d t_{k-1} \dots \int _{t_2} ^x \mathrm d t_1 \, f(t) = \frac 1 {m^k} \int _0 ^x \mathrm d t \, f(t) \int _t ^x \mathrm d t_{k-1} \dots \int _{t_2} ^x \mathrm d t_1 = \\
= \frac 1 {m^k} \int _0 ^x \left[ f(t) \int _{\{t \le t_{k-1} \le \dots \le t_1 \le x\}} 1 \, \mathrm d t_{k-1} \dots \mathrm d t_1 \right] \ .$$

The $k-1$ dimensional integral is just the volume of the $k-1$ dimensional subset (simplex)
$$\{t \le t_{k-1} \le \dots \le t_1 \le x\} \subseteq [t,x] ^{k-1}$$
of which there are exactly $(k-1)!$ identical copies inside the parallelepiped $[t,x] ^{k-1}$, so this volume is exactly $\frac {(x-t)^{k-1}} {(k-1)!}$. Replacing this back in our integral, we get that
$$ f(x) = \frac 1 {m^k} \int _0 ^x f(t) \, \frac {(x-t)^{k-1}} {(k-1)!} \, \mathrm d t$$
for every $k \ge 1$, whence
$$ |f(x)| \le \frac {x^{k-1}} {m^k (k-1)!} \int _0 ^x |f(t)| \, \mathrm d t . $$

Passing to the limit when $k \to \infty$ we get $|f(x)| = 0$, so $f=0$. (We may have passed to the limit directly under the integral, but this would have required the use of some sort of dominated convergence theorem, so I preferred to avoid this route.)

We conclude that no matter who $m \in \mathbb R$ is, the only solution is $f=0$.

Answer (score -1):

Simply differentiate using Newton Lebnitz rule, then solve the differential equation you get.

For Newton Leibniz rule you may want to refer to:
https://byjus.com/jee/newton-leibnitz-theorem/

You can see the solution I have sent.
[solution of question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EL3Qn.jpg)
So yes there exists a real continuous function as exponential function is always continuous.

(I’m too lazy to type using LaTEX, a notebook is faster)
Hope it helps.

Edit : on substituting the f(x) back into the original equation, we get C = 0 (as m can’t be = 0).
So the only solution is given by f(x) = 0

Thanks @Alex M. And @Brian Moehring

Comment: Ok... in this method I got it... but still confused about that of mine.

Comment: Differentiation is not injective.  Have you checked whether your answer is extraneous?

Comment: I have found out the solution, f(x) = C e^(x/m) where C and m are constants

Comment: If you had checked your own solution, you would have had a nasty surprise. Also, if you are too lazy to write in LaTeX, your posts will get deleted. The point is that text can be indexed by search engines, while images cannot.

Comment: Most of those proposed solutions don't work.  In fact there's only one solution: $f(x) = 0$.  It's important to check your solutions whenever a step is not reversible, such as differentiation.

Comment: @Alex. I checked my solutions and found out the surprise, didn’t expect it. And sorry for not typing in LaTEX, usually I send solutions handwritten.

Comment: @BrianMoehring, thanks I checked it and got C = 0. So f(x) = 0 is the only solution.

Comment: Not the best proof technique, though: the OP looks for *continuous* functions $f$, but your reasoning works only for *differentiable* functions.